# Can I fill the remaining horizontal space of a div after a headline that has inline or inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have some headlines with varying lengths. I'd like the space between the end of the headline and the end of the row to be filled with something, like a dotted border. I've tried several methods but they don't all work on all browsers. The best results are on Firefox using display:block ruby (not ideal, I know...) on the headline, and making a span right after the H tag with 100% width. I DO NOT want the headline to have a set width.

I've attached an image of what I'd like to achieve, and have it work with essentially any length headline.

Image example

[image: 1]

I've tried several combinations of flex, inline, inline-block, placing the content in their own div, having the content in the same div, and various other things that might work.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t attach an image, but I think I know what you want to do. The way I would tackle this would be to style the headings as `flex`, then insert an empty pseudo-element which is styled to grow and has a repeating background image containing dots or whatever effect you want.

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5em;
}
h1::after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-image: url(https://donald.net.au/bugs/dotted-wave-2.svg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: auto 20px;
  background-position: left center;
}
```

```html
<h1>One</h1>
<h1>Two is longer</h1>
<h1>Three is very long indeed</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue with this is that it cuts off the large dots I'm using. I wasn't allowed to paste an image but it let me add a link to my original question with an example of what I was hoping to achieve. It DID however lead me to experimenting with flex-grow which I'm less familiar with, and it seems to have worked, so thank you!

Comment: Here is [the definitive guide to flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).